# Why doesn't "ResourceDictionary" work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

My program works well.

```
  <Window.Resources>    

        <ResourceDictionary Source="GlassButton.xaml">
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

But  after adding DataGrid  on the “MainWindow” shows error in string:

```
   <ResourceDictionary Source="GlassButton.xaml">
```

The part of Window.Resources has changed after adding DataGrid and it became like that:

```
<Window.Resources>            
        <ResourceDictionary Source="GlassButton.xaml">
            <my:DepartmentDataSet x:Key="DepartmentDataSet" />
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DepViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=DEP, Source={StaticResource DepartmentDataSet}}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

The error message shows:
"Property "System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent" is called exception.": Number of row "10" and position in a row "29".
With best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found  the reason. I need to put code in "< ResourceDictionary.Merged >". With this added code program works very well!

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="GlassButton.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <my:DepartmentDataSet x:Key="DepartmentDataSet" />
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DepViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=DEP, Source={StaticResource DepartmentDataSet}}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
```